# The dual space of a dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, duality-theorems

[image]

Eh, I don't quite understand the first question. Can someone explain it?

And for the second question, can I say that they have the same dimension. And since the kernel is ${0}$, it is injective. Thus I've solved the second question.
What's more, what is the relationship between the dual space of the dual space, which is $V^{**}$ and $V^*$?

Comment: Do you understand what $\lambda_v$ is? If so, what's unclear about the first part of the question. If not, what are you saying has a kernel of $\{0\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The isomorphism is simply this:
\begin{align*}
V&\longrightarrow V^{**}\\
v&\longmapsto (\lambda_v\colon f\in V^*\mapsto f(v))
\end{align*}
In other words, it associates to each vector $v\in V$, the *evaluation morphism* at $v$.

It's an isomorphism because both spaces have the same dimension, and $\lambda$  is injective.

Comment: Does it matter to use "globally linear" functions, since the composition of 2 of them is not necessarily globally linear (in dimension >1) ? (E.g. $\frac{x_2}{\bar{x}_2}x_1$ and $x_2=y_1+y_2,\bar{x}_2=\bar{y}_2$)